# Limit of $f(x,y)=\frac{y^3}{x^4+\sin^2y}$ as $(x,y)$ goes to $(0,0)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

How to calculate $\lim_{(x, y)\to (0,0)}\frac{y^3}{x^4+\sin^2y}$?

I already evaluated $\lim_{x \to 0} \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{y^3}{x^4+\sin^2y}$ and $\lim_{y \to 0} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{y^3}{x^4+\sin^2y}$, they both equal 0.

What should be my next step? Polar coordinates don't seem like a good idea in this case and I don't know how to properly approximate the function so I could use the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squeeze theorem.

$$\left|\frac{y^3}{x^4+\sin^2y}\right|\leq\left|\frac{y^3}{\sin^2y}\right|$$